# How to add a user define annotation in spring JPA save method

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-annotations

How to add a user define annotation in spring jpa save method only.

I have created a annotation and wanted to use it on the save method of the repository, but the save method is inherited method from CrudRepository of JPA, not sure how can annotation be applied on only that method and not the other method of that repository.

Tried overriding that method in the repository interface and applied the annotation but it didn't worked

Please refer the code below -

**Annotation :**

```
@Target({ ElementType.METHOD })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MyAnnotation {

}

@Aspect
@Configuration
@Slf4j
@ComponentScan(value = "com.somepackage.service")
public class MyAnnotationInterceptor {

   @Value("${val}")
   private String val;

   @Around("@annotation(com.somepackage.service.application.annotation.MyAnnotation)")
   public void around(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
      if("TEST".equalsIgnoreCase(val)){
         log.info("Test Event")
      }else{
         joinPoint.proceed();
      }
   }
}
```

**Repository :**

```
@Transactional
public interface EmployeeEntityRepository extends CrudRepository<EmployeeEntity, String> {

   List<EmployeeEntity> findAllByEmpIdAndStatusNot(String empId, String status);

   @Query("SELECT emp.empId FROM EmployeeEntity emp WHERE emp.orderId IN ?1")
   List<String> findEmployeeIds(List<String> orderIds);

   @Override
   @MyAnnotation
   <S extends EmployeeEntity> Iterable<S> save(Iterable<S> iterable);
}
```

**Service Class:**

```
class EmployeeService {

    @Autowired
    EmployeeEntityRepository employeeEntityRepo;

    public void saveEmployee(List<EmployeeEntity> employeeData) {
        employeeEntityRepo.save(employeeData);
        employeeEntityRepo.clearCache(employeeData);
        /***
        .
        .
        .
        Some other logic calculations 
        .
        .
        ***/
    }

}
```

Comment: It's unclear what's the reason of using that annotation. Maybe there is simpler way to complete you needs without it :)